# Pyspark: How to exclude not null records of a column while calculation pyspark sql function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the statistics for each numerical field. But i got stuck here on how to exclude null while performing this pyspark sql function

```
new_df=data.select([min(line).alias("Min"),max(line).alias("Max"),mean(line).alias("Mean"),stddev(line)])
```

Tried like this, but it gives error

```
new_df=data.select([min(line).alias("Min"),max(line).alias("Max"),mean(line).alias("Mean"),stddev(line.na.fill(0))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filtered the null values using where condition before the select statement by `isNotNull()` function which exclude the null values.

```
new_df=data.where(data.line.isNotNull()).select([min(line).alias("Min"),max(line).alias("Max"),mean(line).alias("Mean"),stddev(line)])
```

Comment: Thank you Sahil. This is very helpful